# Android: Dynamically add TextView on a TableLayout with fixed Width

Tags: android, textview, width, tablelayout, fixed

I'm facing an issue on my android application. I want to dynamically create TableRow in a TableLayout. Each of this row needs to contain 4 TextViews. 
I want the TextView like this:

- textview1: 40% of the screen
- textview2: 10% of the screen
- textview3: 10% of the screen
- textview5: 40% of the screen

I manage to create the Tewtview dynamically but the size are not respected. For example if my first textview contains a big text, it covers all the screen instead of only 40% and multiline.

I read a lot of similar questions but can't find the solution here. Here is my layout file:

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
android:id="@+id/journee_contenu">

<TableRow>
  <!-- Column 1 -->
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tbl_txt1"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="4"
     android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      />

  <!-- Column 2 -->
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tbl_txt2"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="bbbbb"
     />

  <!-- Column 3 -->
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tbl_txt3"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:text="ccccc"
      />
      <!-- Column 4 -->
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tbl_txt4"
     android:layout_width="0dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="4"
     android:text="ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
      />
</TableRow>
```

The Layout creates a static tab with a first row that is as I want it to be. But the rows added dynamically are not behaving the same way.

My dynamic code:

```
    TableLayout genLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.journee_contenu);
for (MatchWrapper match : matchs) {
    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tvEq1 = new TextView(this);
    tvEq1.setText(match.getEquipe1());
    TextView tvSc1 = new TextView(this);
    tvSc1.setText(match.getScore_equipe1());
    TextView tvSc2 = new TextView(this);
    tvSc2.setText(match.getScore_equipe2());
    TextView tvEq2 = new TextView(this);
    tvEq2.setText(match.getEquipe2());
    tr1.addView(tvEq1);
    tr1.addView(tvSc1);
    tr1.addView(tvSc2);
    tr1.addView(tvEq2);
    genLayout.addView(tr1);
}
```

My match object is only containing string with various size. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your dynamicly added `TableRows` don't do as you would like is that you do not set the `LayoutParams` for the `TableRow` nor the `TextViews`.

On each `TextView` you add `LayoutParams` like this:

```
tvEq1.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4 ) );
tvSc1.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );
tvSc2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );
tvEq2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4 ) );
```

The last parameter of the `LayoutParams`-constructor is the `layout_weight`.

You need to add the `LayoutParams` before addind the `TextViews` to the `TableRow`.

You might need to add `LayoutParams` to your `TableRow` aswell.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kasper! I tried a lot but it looks like it was as simple as that!